# Find whether a List of type is contained in a List of Lists of type

Tags: c#, linq

Is there a LINQ way to find out whether, for example:

```
List<int> micro = new List<int>(){1,2,3,4,5};
```

is in a

```
List<List<int>> macro = new List<List<int>>();
```

?

I can do a `foreach` loop on macro and check whether it contains at least one `List` that has all of micro's items `(macro[0].Contains(1) && macro[0].Contains(2)...)`, but is there a more C# way to do it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
bool exists = macro.Any(x => micro.All(x.Contains));
```

If the order and the number of element is important use `SequenceEqual`

```
bool exists = macro.Any(x => x.SequenceEqual(micro));
```

Comment: Yes. Just be aware, that this does *not* necessarily mean, that `macro` contains the exact `micro` object. It "just" means that `macro` contains an `IEnumerable` which has the same items as `micro`. Also, that `IEnumerable` might have *more* items than `micro`.

Comment: Can use `object.ReferenceEquals()` in the `Any()` if you're looking for exactly the same list instance.

Comment: @MatthewWatson or just Contains:  `macro.Contains(micro)`

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications! In my case, this is exactly what I need. I need to make sure I have not added a List/HashSet in a different permutation to a List/HashSet of Lists/HashSets.

Comment: @Tyress If you're concerned about different permutations, neither of these answers is what you want. The first is too permissive (the sets in `macro` could contain *more* elements than `micro`) and the second is too restrictive (checks order as well as contents).

Comment: You can combine the first with `&& x.Count == micro.Count`. But that would still say that `{1, 1, 2, 2, 2}` would equal `{1, 1, 1, 2, 2}`. --- so you could temporarily sort the lists and then check if they are sequenceequal. If that's really necessary.

Answer (score -1):

Please try following, its working fine.

```
        string listElems = string.Join(",",micro);
        bool exists = macro.Any(x=>string.Join(",",x)==listElems);
```

Hope this will be fine for you. :)
Happy coding.

Comment: Please don't. Building strings and then checking the string equality has horrible performance. Also, this way, the sequence of items is important, which OP does not seem to want. So this basically does `macro.Any(x => x.SequenceEqual(micro))` only worse.