# Algorithm to check if double list contains one list - if not then add that one list

Tags: c#

I'm trying to check if double list of strings 'questions' contains one list of string 'groupOfQuestions'. If it doesn't contain then the program will add 'groupOfQuestions' to the 'questions'. Otherwise it won't add.
This is the way I tried to this but it seems like it's an endless loop:

```
if (questions.Count != 0)
{
     int r = 0;
     foreach (List<string> q in questions.ToList())
     {
          if (q.Except(groupOfQuestions).Any())
          {
                 r++;
          }
     }
     if (questions.Count == r)
     {
          questions.Add(groupOfQuestions);
     }
}
else
{
     questions.Add(groupOfQuestions);
}
```

EDIT:
Double list: `List<List<string>> questions` and `List<string> groupOfQuestions`

For example:

```
questions[0] = {{aaa},{bbb},{ccc}}
questions[1] = {{ddd},{eee},{fff}}
```

1. `groupOfQuestions = {{ggg},{hhh},{iii}}`
   questions[0] and questions[1] haven't got the same content as the
   groupOfQuestions has so the program should add groupOfQuestions to
   questions (`questions[2] = {{ggg},{hhh},{iii}}`)
2. `groupOfQuestions = {{fff},{eee},{ddd}}`
   questions[0] hasn't got but questions[1] has got the same content as the
   groupOfQuestions so the program shouldn't add groupOfQuestions to
   questions

Comment: Could you, please, provide an example? Sample data?

Comment: What do you mean by "double list"? Do you mean `List<List<String>>`? (if so, then it's a "list-of-lists-of-string" not a "double list")

Comment: What does "one list of string 'groupOfQuestions'" mean?

Comment: Your code is not complete. What are the types of `questions` and `groupOfQuestions`?

Comment: I don't know why it won't add this to my edit: List<List<string>> questions and List<string> groupOfQuestions

Comment: Ok, that'll help (I've formatted the code for you - you can use backticks around short pieces of code).

Comment: Thanks. I didn't konw that.

Comment: I asked this question before, and it was answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25971454/1685167).

Comment: Yes but this is the answer I already know. I would like to know how can I add the list which doesn't match with no other list in list of lists of strings.

Comment: If the order of the items isn't important I'd probably use `HashSet<string>`'s instead - they provide some useful functionality, such as `SetEquals` which determines if two sets contain the same elements. Either way, you only need to check whether any child list in `questions` contains the same elements as `groupOfQuestions`. Once you know that you know whether or not to add `groupOfQuestions` to `questions`. What exactly are you having trouble with?

Comment: I'm having a problem with remembering if any child list in questions contains the same elements as groupOfQuestions. If I make this in second if: questions.Add(groupOfQuestions) groupOfQuestions will be added as many times as there is different child items in questions.

Comment: Don't add the group of questions within the loop - use the loop only to check if any lists contain the same items. You can store the result in a boolean. Then add those questions (or not). Remember, you can break out of loops using `break` - once you find a list with the same items it's not necessary to continue checking the rest.

Comment: I figured it out. My code is also good but the problem was that it stuck in an endless loop because I told the program to make 6 combinations out of 3 questions (2 questions per combination). This was in other part of code. Thank you all for helping

Answer (score -3):

you can use .contains function. for more details please visit [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3(v=vs.110).aspx)